# Why does Django not pass on error messages with the default 404 view?

Tags: django

(Context: I'm still very new to both Django and web development.)

**1) Could someone explain the reasoning for the following statement?** [This Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621173/404-error-messages-in-django) answered the question of *how* to deal with it, but not why it might be a good/bad idea.

[The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) state, "The page_not_found view should 
suffice for 99% of Web applications, but if you want to override it, 
you can specify handler404 in your URLconf".

That is, the page_not_found view only passes on the requested URL and ignores 
any message you provide when raising an exception. It seems to me that 
having the *option* to provide helpful hints to the 404.html template 
by default would be good for everyone.

**2) I'm currently making a custom view so that I can pass on helpful messages for the following situation. Is there some reason I shouldn't?**

I'm using matrix URLs so the base resource is 
a normal hierarchical URL followed by matrix options in the basic 
format of: 
;filter_type1=item:value,item:value;filter_type2=item:value...

So it is quite easy to provide helpful messages based on how far along 
the parsing gets before having an error. It seems helpful to me to pass 
on a message such as the following:

- "Allowed filter_types are: type1, type2, type3." or
- "Allowed items for filter_type a are: item1, item2, item3."

Apologies if I missed this explanation elsewhere. I've looked and I [asked on google django-users](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/c4609dc0abb2a821/d6f251f99618d680?show_docid=d6f251f99618d680&pli=1) but got no replies.

Comment: It feels like the question has only been indirectly answered. However based on the answers so far, I must assume that the answer is: if you need an error message in a 404, you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what the question is. The [page_not_found](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/views/defaults.py#L11) view is basic by default because there aren't that many situations where you need to explain why the page wasn't found except that it wasn't.

I presume by 'matrix options' you mean URL/GET parameters like:

```
http://domain.com/page/?option1=value&option2=value..
```

Instead of throwing a 404 if they enter an incorrect combination of parameter, why not default to the base url/template (http://domain.com/page/) with an error message saying "Option1 can only be x,y,z". This way they are presented with a familiar page and can retry their selection without having to navigate back from a 404 page (and it isn't so confusing as to why it didn't work).

You can use django's [messaging framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) to easily accomplish this (I've done so in the past). Pass an error message to the template when you are checking the parameters in the view.

Comment: "...is basic by default because there aren't that many situations where you need to explain why the page wasn't found..." I have only seen assertions such as yours and the documentation's that there aren't many situations for the message. I can totally accept that it is true perhaps, but I am looking for more than assertion. Your explanation on the second part helps me by saying that it may not be "wrong" to show an error message but that there may be a better way to do it. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: What reasons can you think of why a page could not be found. (1) a link was broken, (2) a user typed it in wrong (see #1). If there are any other reasons, like invalid data was entered, it should not be a 404. Use other HTTP response codes to show that a response failed. 409: conflicting data, 403: forbidden, etc.

Comment: Fair enough. I have wondered about this myself. Similar to my comment to Matthew, let's say the filter/order parameters in the URL appear to be malformed. Is that not 404? Maybe I am barking up the wrong tree. I did look through all the HTTP responses and didn't find a more appropriate one.

Comment: I'd return a 409: Conflict. (Or a plain 400: Error). If you are just rendering HTML, however, then you'd return a 200, but the page data shows there is an error. (Most of my web-application programming is API based, where 4xx series responses can and do have a body.)

Answer (score 1):

If your data is coming in like:

```
http://example.com/foo;bar;baz
```

Then you are doing it wrong :)

You then need to use regular expressions to parse the data that is to be processed.

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

(Zawinski, 1997)

Instead, as pastylegs suggests, use GET parameters.

Even better, make use of the django form handling and:

- create a form, that has validation rules
- render the input page from that form
- parse the user input using the form
- display data if form was valid, else display validation errors alongside user input

You can do this with GET requests, or POST requests. POST has the advantage of having 'clean' urls, and longer data body. GET means that urls can be bookmarked.

What this all comes down to is using the right parts of the framework for the right tasks. URL routing uses regular expressions to work out which URL hits which view. The simpler you make the url patterns, the easier they will be to maintain. User input should be handled by forms.

Comment: Point taken on "doing it wrong." Just to explain... after reading RESTful web development and [Matrix URIs (1996)](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/MatrixURIs.html) by Tim Berners-Lee I was inspired to write a system for handling matrix URIs with the semicolon format. It's a more flexible system than query, but it's just not implemented in frameworks so yes it needs parsing :)

Comment: As for the content of the parameters, they are not user input per se. They are filters and ordering directions for lists of data that will appear on the page. They can be modified by the user if some controls are provided. So in this situation, let's say I convert to using a query string and GET parameters, what is the right way to go for e.g. malformed filter/order parameters in the query string?

Comment: My position is that if the user selects things, and then this affects the incoming data, then it is user input. It is likely validated somewhat by the client-side of your application, but should still be validated by the server. As for ordering: if you use mappings (and to use a form, you will), that goes away. Incorrect data: -> re-render the form showing how the data conflicts.

Comment: To make it clearer: don't get fixated on the fact that a form is usually HTML fields. If you can, make your page controls update hidden fields within a <form> element, that is then posted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason you are having trouble understanding this is, you are trying to mix 2 different issues.

First, is the issue of whether the actual page was found or not.
Second, is the issue of whether the parameters provided were valid or not.

So, if the (partial) url is:

```
    .../whatever/?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

If the page `/whatever/default` is **not found**, you will (should) be shown a `"404 Page not found"` type of error message. In this case, **you can't tell** if the parameters or values provided were correct. The requested page doesn't exist, so you don't know which page the parameters were meant for. You can't even assume that the correct `domain name` was specified. There may be many arbitrary domains, urls, and pages where the parameters are valid, and many others where the parameters are invalid.

If the page `/whatever/default` **is found**, then:
If specifying the wrong parameters might cause that page to load/redirect a non existent page, then that should be prevented by that page. If necessary, it should be up to that page to validate the parameters provided, and take appropriate actions and show appropriate messages.