# Django: Display error message passed by Http404("msg") in custom 404 error handler

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, extract-error-message

Using django 1.11, I have defined a custom 404 handler, by writing in my main URLs.py:

```
handler404 = 'myApp.views.myError'
```

The function `myError()` looks like this:

```
def myError(request):
    #errorMsg=request.error_404_message
    return render(request,'404.html')
```

This function works when I call `raise Http404("My msg")`.
However, when I try to get the message passed by the `Http404` call (see commented section in myError), my code crashes:

> Server Error (500)

How can I then get the error message? I read a lot of questions about it [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621173/how-to-display-the-message-passed-to-http404-in-a-custom-404-error-template-in-d/37109914), but most answers refer to getting the message in the html file and not in a custom python error handler function.

*EDIT:* The problem is, that I cannot see the debug page, because the error obviously only occurs when myError() is called and this happens only, if `debug=False` in the settings.

Comment: Instead of saying `Server Error (500)`, you should include the full traceback, from your logs/error email.

Comment: @Alasdair see edit. Is there another possibly to see the debug page? I don't get an error in the terminal

Comment: You're right, you can't see the yellow error page, because you need to set `DEBUG=False` to test the custom 404 page. I would expect to see the traceback in your logs, or the email that is sent to the site admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request does not have a `error_404_message` attribute by default, so `request.error_404_message` will give you an error.

[The answer you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34973670/113962) sets it as an attribute, but I do not see why you would want to do this in Django 1.9+, since you already have access to the exception in the view.

The signature of your custom view should be:

```
def myError(request, exception, template_name='404.html'):
    ...
```

You now have access to `exception`. You can look at the [default page not found view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34973670/113962) to how it extracts the message from the exception.