# Django Test message passed in with Http404

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm trying to check if my app passes a message alongside my Http404 call. However I've not been able to access that message inside the tests, only via hacking manually in shell.

my_app.views.py:

```py
from django.http import Http404
def index(request):
    raise Http404("My message")
```

Then in this app's test file I call:

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

class AppIndexView(TestCase):
    def test_index_view(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse("my_app:index"))

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
        # This checks

        self.assertEqual(response.context["reason"], "My message"
        # This gives: KeyError: 'reason'
        # However if I manually trace these steps I can access this key.

        self.assertContains(response, "My Message")
        # This gives: AssertionError: 404 != 200 : Couldn't
        # retrieve content: Response code was 404 (expected 200)
        # This is in accordance with the previous status_code check, so:

        self.assertContains(response, "My Message", status_code=404)
        # This gives: AssertionError: False is not true : Couldn't find 'My
        # Message' in response
```

I also have tried various version to get that message with response.exception, response.context.exception etc. as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621173/how-to-display-the-message-passed-to-http404-in-a-custom-404-error-template-in-d/37109914#37109914)

If I execute in django's shell I can access that message in two different ways:

```py
>>> from django.test import Client
>>> from django.urls import reverse
>>> from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
>>> setup_test_environment()
>>> client=Client()
>>> response = client.get(reverse("my_app:index"))
>>> response.context["reason"]
'My Message'
>>> response.content
b'[lots of html...]<div id="info">\n    \n      <p>My Message</p>\n    \n  </div>[...some more html]
```

How can I get access to this message in my tests.py?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the content of an `HttpResponse` object by its `content` attribute:

```
>>> from django.http import HttpResponse
>>> obj = HttpResponse('my message')
>>> obj.content
b'my message'
```

<s>Therefore, you should be able to compare `response.content` with your desired result in your test:</s>

Edit: the test below will fail, because `response.content` will contain the complete rendered HTML, which may or may not include the original exception message.

```
class AppIndexView(TestCase):
    def test_index_view(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse("my_app:index"))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
        self.assertEqual(response.content, "My message")
```

The reason why you were able to manually resolve `response.context["reason"]` is because Django probably set the key `reason` in the default 404 template context, which is not something you can access from the client side.

Comment: Using ```self.assertEqual(response.content, "My message")``` gives me an ```AssertionError: b'\n<!doctype html>\n<html lang="en">\n<h[146 chars]l>\n' != 'My Message'```, because ```response``` contains the entire html. I guess using the default ```Http404()``` delivers a template, not just a simple ```HttpResponse```.

But using ```self.assertContains(response, "My Message")``` checks for ```response.content``` anyway and raises the AssertionError as posted in my question.

Does Django deliver the 404 page with ```DEBUG=False``` when testing?

Comment: You are right, and my answer was incorrect. The response object you are testing will always contain the rendered HTML with no easy way to discern the original `reason` message, short of grepping through in in the HTML...