# django-rest-framwork: AttributeError, 'Response' object has no attribute 'title'

Tags: python, django

**AttributeError:** Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `title` on serializer `QuestionSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Response` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Response' object has no attribute 'title'.

**models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(null=False,blank=False)
    status = models.CharField(default='inactive',max_length=10)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('poll/<int:id>/', PollDetailsAPIView.as_view()),
]
```

**serializers.py**

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields =[
            'id',
            'title',
            'status',
            'created_by'
        ]
```

**views.py**

```
class PollDetailsAPIView(APIView):
    
    def get_object(self, id):
        try:
            return Question.objects.get(id=id)
        except Question.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"error": "Question does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    
    def get(self, request, id):
        question = self.get_object(id)
        serializer = QuestionSerializer(question)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

on postman, i am trying to get an id that doesnt exist but instead of getting this response `"error": "Question does not exist"` and an `Error: 404`, i keep getting `error 500 Internal server error`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are trying to get non existing object, your `get_object` method returns a `Response`, which is then passed to the serializer. Since it cannot serialize `Response`, it raises an `AttributeError`. What you should do is either raising an `Http404` error in `except`:

```py
def get_object(self, id):
    try:
        return Question.objects.get(id=id)
    except Question.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('Not found')
```

or use django shortcut `get_object_or_404`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


class PollDetailsAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, id=id)
        serializer = QuestionSerializer(question)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: The problem is it was working with Function based views but when i tried switching to class based views i kept getting this error.

Comment: Also, if i follow Http404, how do i custom the message since any text inside " " does not work?

Comment: @kd12345 try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621173/11544538)

Comment: I am not using any templates, i want to change the message that appears in the json object currently i am getting this `{"detail": "Not found."}`

Comment: ah, sorry, my bad. Then you can try `from rest_framework.exceptions import NotFound`, and raise it instead of `Http404`: `raise NotFound('<Custom message>')`